# Calculating electric flux through a sphere (calculus)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

This problem comes with two parts, and the reason I am posting here is that they are both supposed to result in the same answer but I am getting two different values.

A spherical shell of radius $R$ is centered on the origin and an electric field
$$E = [K \cdot s^2,0,0]~\text{in cylindrical}~[s,\phi,z]$$

**First, calculate the flux by integrating E dot dA through the shell.**

I believe I'm only integrating where the radius $= R$, so I set $s = R \cdot  \cos\theta$ and used the fact that when integrating around the circle $E \cdot dA$ would just become $\cos\theta \cdot E$, where $E$ is now $K \cdot \cos^2\theta \cdot R^2$.  I'm now left with  $$\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^3\theta \cdot~\text{a constant}~d\theta$$ which gives me an end result that the flux $= 0$, which makes intuitive sense because all the flux that is entering is leaving at the same rate.

**Now calculate the flux using Gauss' Therem**

So here I started by finding the divergence of $E$, I got $3 \cdot K \cdot s$. I think I'm fine there.  I then substitute in for terms in spherical units, so $s = r \cdot \sin\phi$.  I now have that my flux $=$ integral through the volume of a sphere where   $f = r^3 \cdot \sin\phi$
so $$\text{flux} = 3 \cdot k \int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^R  r^3 \cdot \sin\phi~dr~d\theta~d\phi$$

This leave me with an answer of $F = 3 \cdot \pi \cdot K \cdot R^2$

**My thoughts on where I went wrong**

The only thing I can think that I may have done wrong is:
assuming my second answer is correct I may have to overlooked the orientation of $dA$ when integrating for the first part, this having the two halves of $F$ cancel each other out.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

[I drew this](http://prntscr.com/6vvees) picture to show my thought process on part 1. I know that this is wrong, but I can't seem to decipher what would be the right representation of the sphere in the z-s plane. (Is this even a proper depiction of what would be seen in the "z-s plane"?
I'm starting to think I should just scrap the whole z-s plane idea I'm not sure if that is even a legit thing. Would a double integral with a fixed r=R work?

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: could you explain why that is? [I drew this picture](http://prntscr.com/6vvees) to show the θ that I'm working with, and am integrating around that circle. It seems to me that E⋅dA would be max when θ = 0. I'm not sure where my train of though it going wrong

Comment: now that I think about it, the axes on that picture don't make much sense. I'm not sure how to properly depict the sz plane.